# POST request in GWT

Tags: gwt, post

i first tried to make request to server with `GET` method and it works fine. my request would process a file then return as a pdf file and would open on a new browser. what i did is overriding the `doGet()` method. since having a `GET` request is only limited to few parameters, i must change it to `doPost()` mehod but the problem is that it can't be overrided because the method is final.

in an `HTML FORM`, what i wanted to happen is something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://differentdomain.com/appserv/appserv.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="fwi_script" value="app/custom/cusapp/interface" />
  <input type="hidden" name="trx" value="&lt;trx&gt;
    &lt;productid&gt;PROD1&lt;/productid&gt;
    ....../** transaction details here */
    &lt;/trx&gt;" />

  <input type="hidden" name="fcompanyid" value="SHOST101" />
  <input type="hidden" name="fwi_action" value="PRINT_PENDING_SALES" />
  <input type="hidden" name="fexcel" value="0" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

this html form will print the order slip of every transaction when user clicks on the post order button.

anyone can give an idea on how to `POST` request in `GWT` server? i think i can't do it with `RequestBuilder` since i will be having the `SOP` problem since i will be connecting to a different domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build very nearly the same html you have in your question, start with a `FormPanel` and add the form fields you need to it. Make sure to configure the `FormPanel` with the correct action and method, and to provide names (and possibly values) to the fields added to it. To fire off the request, `submit()` can be called.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make a normal GWT RPC call to your server and have the server make the POST request to the server located on a different domain.

Comment: with regards to make the rpc do the work, can i use jav.net.* for this to handle and establish the connection?

Comment: From your server code you can use any JRE class or third party library you like.